# How do you set the alternative hypothesis text string in a `htest` object in R?

Tags: r, function

I am creating a hypothesis test in `R` as a [`htest` object](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.1/topics/htest.object).  I have managed to create the object I want, with the required estimate, test statistic and p-value.  My only remaining problem is that the statement I want to give for my alternative hypothesis does not conform to the textual structure used in the [printing method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.1/topics/print.htest) for an `htest` object.  The setup for these objects seems to assume you have an alternative hypothesis that is a one-sided or two-sided test operating on an unknown parameter.  It does not appear to accomodate more generate statements of alternative hypotheses, such as for goodness-of-fit tests.  To be a bit more specific about my problem, here is the textual structure of the output print message for a `htest` object:

```
alternative hypothesis: true [name(null.value)] is [less than/equal to/greater than] [null.value]
```

I would like a more general print output like this:

```
alternative hypothesis: [character string]
```

When you create a `htest` object you can set `name(null.value)` and `null.value` to any character string you want, so it is possible to alter the start an end parts of the print message to anything you want.  You can also set `alternative` to `NA` and this removes the middle part.  However, the intermediate words "true" and "is" seem to be fixed.  This means that you seem to be stuck with a message with the structure `true [character string] is [character string]`.

---

**My question:** When creating a `htest` object, is there any way to get a print message for the alternative hypothesis that is an arbitrary character string?  If so, what is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: yes, it seems like you already know how: `structure(list(alternative = '[character string]'), class = 'htest')`

Comment: @rawr: I'm not sure how you implement this with the ```structure``` function.  If I already have an ```htest``` object, how do I do this?  (Could you show this in an answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you set `x$null.value <- NULL`, it will print any string you construct for `x$alternative`

```
x <- t.test(1:10)
x$null.value <- NULL
x$alternative <- sprintf('%.2f on %s degrees of freedom, p %s',
                         x$statistic, x$parameter, format.pval(x$p.value, eps = 0.001))
x

# One Sample t-test
# 
# data:  1:10
# t = 5.7446, df = 9, p-value = 0.0002782
# alternative hypothesis: 5.74 on 9 degrees of freedom, p < 0.001
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  3.334149 7.665851
# sample estimates:
# mean of x 
#       5.5
```